# another "Can't find resource for bundle com.ibm.ws.install.internal.resources.InstallKernel, key ERROR_IMPROPER_httpPROXY_FORMAT"

Tags: open-liberty

I'm trying to install a feature on open liberty 23.0.0.12 on windows.

```
featureUtility.bat installFeature servlet-3.0
```

I'm getting this error

```
Can't find resource for bundle com.ibm.ws.install.internal.resources.InstallKernel, key ERROR_IMPROPER_httpPROXY_FORMAT
```

No other apps are having proxy issues.   Where are the proxy settings for this utility?  I see this article, but I don't have a {wlp.install.dir}/etc/  directory.